# How to find list of all subdomains internally at company

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, internal-dns, dns-zone

I am a software developer and seems that will moving to a new building and wanting to make backups etc..   I am realizing that with 8 web servers , some of which are new and others windows 2000...   **apparently subdomains for clients are everywhere**

Seems that a Network engineer quit and now it falls into my lap.

1. I can see the name server records on any given register icann of which that IP Address it ping responds back with I assume is ours.
2. From what I recall it is **CNAME or A  records**  and there are "Zones" to setup
3. Most likely there **should be an internal DNS server** that would tell me ALL the subdomains and what IP addresses that they point at etc.  right?

**How can I figure out where these subdomains are** ?   I can see my static ip, gateway, primary and secondary ip addresses and then the  mycompany.com  ip address from the outside  ... **but how do I find the internal zones of these subdomains?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all subdomains that you care about are accessible from outside your network:

1. Find the whois record of your domains, it normally contains the name servers.
2. From the nameservers identify the service running your DNS records. Typically there is a website associated with the same domain name. Worse you may need to do reverse DNS lookups to find the service. Even worse the service may have resellers and you need to find yours.

   3. The service should be able to provide you with a list of subdomains and IP addresses. Map these to your network. Of course there may be outdated records, which you somehow have to invalidate.

Now inside your network, it's harder:

- any outside IP address will map to one server on an internal port. There may also be one router per IP address and theoretically http and HTTPS may go to different servers. Your subdomains could also be advertised with non standard port numbers and your company may offer other services, such as FTP, SSH etc.
- any server mapped to may proxy some or all requests to another server.

You need to follow all these links to the end and identify the location and setup of each subdomain.